# Input selector not being reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML that looks like:

```
<input type="number">
<br>
<input type="number">
<br>
<input type="number">
<br>
<button>+</button>
```

And my JS

```
$('input').on('click', function () {
    var input = $(this);
    $('button').on('click', function () {
        var newVal = parseInt(input.val()) + 1;
        input.val(newVal);
    });
});
```

Everytime I switch input to edit the value using the plus button, the previously clicked inputs also gets changed.

How can I do this properly so that only "this" selected input gets edited?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qh8sqd09/

Answer (score 0):

Save the last clicked input in a variable. When you click the plus button, you add to the value of the last clicked input.

```
var last_clicked;

$('input').on('click', function () {
    last_clicked = $(this);
});

$('button').on('click', function () {
    var newVal = parseInt(last_clicked.val()) + 1;
    last_clicked.val(newVal);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qh8sqd09/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest means by which this could be achieved, I think, is to assign a class-name (or a custom `data-*` attribute) to the last-clicked element and, on clicking the `<button>` look for the element with that class-name (or custom attribute) as an identifier. For example:

```js
// select all the <input> elements,
// binding an anonymous function to handle the focus event:
$('input').on('focus', function() {
  // selecting the <input> elements with the 'lastActive'
  // class-name, removing that class:
  $('input.lastActive').removeClass('lastActive');
  // adding the 'lastActive' class-name to the focused element:
  $(this).addClass('lastActive');
});

// selecting the <button> element, and binding an event-handler
// for the click event:
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
  // preventing the default action of a <button> (usually,
  // when wrapped in a <form> the <button> submits that <form>:
  e.preventDefault();

  // finding the <input> element with the 'lastActive' class-name,
  // updating its value:
  $('input.lastActive').val(function(i, v) {
    // first argument (here: 'i'), the index of the current element
    // in the jQuery collection,
    // second argument (here: 'v'), the current value held by the
    // <input> element

    // if v is a falsey-value, we return 1 otherwise
    // we parse the attribute-value with parseFloat (to
    // ensure it's a number) and add 1 to that number:
    return !v ? 1 : parseFloat(v) + 1;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" />
<br />
<input type="number" />
<br />
<input type="number" />
<br />
<button>+</button>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).
- jQuery:

  - [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
  - [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
  - [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).